# How would you make a horizontal picker view in sprite kit to choose different characters?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a game in SWIFT (SpriteKit) where the user can pick between a large amount of characters to play as during the game. The 'characters' would be in what looks like a horizontal picker view. It is similar to the app "Ball King's" player chooser that looks like this:

[image: image 1]

and

[image: image 2]

I do not know where to start and any help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up a UISwipeGestureRecognizer in your view. When a swipe is detected, get the direction of the swipe and either display the next or previous sprite with an animation. If you haven't used gesture recognizers documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)UISwipeGestureRecognizer). Another option is to simply detect swipes generically using touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc.